# JPA 2.0: Annotation of foreign ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate and JPA 2.0. I have a Mail class and a MailAccount class. Neither class has a need to have direct references to the other, the Mail class currently just has an accountId long that points to the ID of the account it belongs to. This is for constructing queries, such as 'Get all mails that belong to account X'. Giving them a direct reference to eachother is bad for many reasons (There may be hundreds of thousands of mails tied to an account), as far as I can tell.

However, in doing this I'm not annotating the accountId field with any JPA annotations. I'd like to make the database aware of the relationship, mainly that accountId is referencing the ID of an entry in the mail account table (For cascading changes and whatnot). How do I do this, with JPA?

In short:

*in Mail.java*

```
private long accountId;
```

*in MailAccount.java*

```
private long id;
```

How do I, via JPA, tell Hibernate/JPA that accountId is referring to a MailAccount.id ?

Comment: Do the right thing, and create a ManyToOne assciation. You're not foced to make it bidirectional. And even if it was bidirectional, OneToMany associations are lazy, so it wouldn't make any difference.